# get all values from one class to anothed class method

Tags: java, swing, resultset

I have an class `IntegrationWithDB` in which i have to method `getConnection()`and selectFromDB().

- In the selectFromDb() i have a result set , i want to get the result
  set vales in another class method
- Actually it did but it only shows the last value of dataBase table.
- Note i have made getter and setter method in `IntegrationWithDB` class and use in `selectFromDB()` method.

  public void selectFromDB() {

  ```
      try {
          if (this.conn == null) {
              this.getConnection();
          }

          if (this.stmt == null) {
              this.stmt = this.conn.createStatement();
          }

          int success = 0;
          this.query = "select * from contacts order by node_id";

         this.rs = this.stmt.executeQuery(query);
         // something is wrong in the while loop
          while (rs.next()) {

              setId(rs.getInt("node_id"));                               // i made getter and setter for id, name, parent and for level
              setNam(rs.getString("node_name"));
              setParnt(rs.getString("node_parent"));
              setLvl(rs.getInt("node_parent"));


          }



          if (success == 0) {
              this.conn.rollback();
          } else {
              this.conn.commit();
          }
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
  ```

and in another class `test` i have method `displayList()` in this method i write the following code

```
public class test {


     IntegrationWithDbClass qaz = new IntegrationWithDbClass();

    public  void displayList ( ) {


       qaz.getConnection();
       qaz.selectFromDB();


       for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++){
        System.out.println(" "+qaz.getId()); 
         System.out.println(" "+qaz.getNam());
       }

          }
```

when i initilize the `displayList()` method in the main method , it shows the following result

```
5
red
```

how can i get all the five values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have to create what is commonly referred to as an `Entity` class. This is the class that represents a **single row** in your database. This should ideally be separate from the code that interacts with the database connection.

So first step, create a class named `Contact`, and in it put the 4 fields you have, `id`, `name`, `parent` and `level`, with the respective getter methods. If you do not expect these to change by your program make them immutable, it is the good practice to ensure consistency. So something like:

```
public class Contact {

   private final int id;
   private final String name;
   private final String parent;
   private final String level;

   public Contact(String id, String name, String parent, String level) {
     this.id = id;
     this.name = name;
     this.parent = parent;
     this.level = level;
   }

   public int getId() {
     return id;
   }

   //... put the rest of the getter methods
}
```

Then in your `IntegrationWithDB` class (I would rename this to something more meaningful like `ContactRepository`) you can change that method you have to:

```
public List<Contact> getContacts() {
   // ... your database connection and query code here

   this.rs = this.stmt.executeQuery(query);

   List<Contact> contacts = new LinkedList<Contact>();

   while (rs.next()) {

      int id = rs.getInt("node_id");                               
      String name = rs.getString("node_name");
      String parent = rs.getString("node_parent");
      String level = setLvl(rs.getInt("level"));

      contacts.add(new Contact(id, name, parent, level));
   }

   //... the rest of your database handling code, don't forget to close the connection

   return contacts;
 }
```

Then from `displayList()` you just have to call `getContacts()` which gives you a list of `Contact` objects to iterate through.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that currently you're storing those properties in int/string variables. In every iteration of the loop you're overwriting the values. What you need to do is to store them in some collection like ArrayList and in each iteration add() to this collection.

Comment: Can i store it in the linkHashMap?

Comment: can you show me how can i store the values in linkedHashMap through code?

Comment: The question is why you want LinkedHashMap for that? When I think about that probably the best option would be to create some additional class like Node to store data about given node. Then create an ArrayList of Nodes and in every iteration of the loop create a new Node and add it to the List